# How to let users to block private messages in Django-postman?

Tags: django, django-views

I have instlled django-postman but it works great. However some I'd like to allow users to opt for not receiving any private messages. I'm wondering how the easiest way to do so?

I've looked at the [docs](http://django-postman.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html) but could not find such settings so I guess it requires some hacking the source but I'm not sure where and how it should be applied. So appreciate your hints.

Answer (score 0):

Your need should likely be fulfilled by one of these features: `User filter` or `Exchange filter`.

Comment: Looking at the docs, I could not figure out how to do so. Can you elaborate please?